# Trigger cannot see boolean field

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a trigger in postgres 13 through pgAdmin and its working fine for updating string columns in the database but fails when trying to update a boolean field. Error: `ERROR:  record "new" has no field "soldout"`

```
CREATE TABLE "Item" (
    "id" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "description" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "price" MONEY NOT NULL,
    "available" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "purchased" INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    "soldOut" BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false

    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

pgAdmin Trigger

```
BEGIN

    IF NEW.purchased >= NEW.available THEN
        
        NEW.name := 'Test Name';
        NEW.soldOut := true; <----- fails
    
    END IF;
    
    RETURN NEW;

END;
```

Comment: The column name is mixed case, you need to double quote it in the trigger function to preserve the case.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Perfect! I cant believe i spent a hour trying to figure that out.. Can you create an answer so i can mark it? Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks. I will not create an answer as this is a common error. Also sooner or later someone is going to mark this as a duplicate anyway.

Comment: The best solution is to no create table or column names that require double quotes. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names